# passing std::array to a function: default value

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a function signature as follows:

```
void analyze(Image * x, std::array<bool, 4> smooth);
```

What I would like is to give this array smooth a default value if the user does not explicitly set this in the call. So I tried something like:

```
std::array<bool, 4> smooth = std::array<bool, 4>
                               ({true, true, true, false}));
void analyze(Image * x, std::array<bool, 4> smooth = std::array<bool, 4>(({true, true, true, false})));
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get it to compile. The example above says "error: expected expression".

Comment: The first version works fine: http://goo.gl/47WCPj. Are you using an older compiler?

Comment: Kill the parentheses.

Comment: [First version works fine](http://ideone.com/y6zuH4)

Comment: did you #include <array> ?

Comment: Its the double brackets in `smooth = std::array<bool, 4>(({true, true, true, false}))` which makes my gcc choke complaining that `statement-expressions are not allowed outside functions`. If I change it to `smooth = std::array<bool, 4>({true, true, true, false})` everything is o.k. Why that is so a C++ linguist might explain...

Comment: It is not an stl array. It is `std::array`. The STL didn't have an `array` class template.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I tried killing the parentheses but not luck on the clang compiler:
void analyze(Image * x, std::array<bool, 4> smooth = std::array<bool, 4>({true, true, true, false}));

Still gets the problem of expected expression.

Comment: @Luca +1 for question though do remember STL is not the Standard C++ library; *(I mis-speak too on that sometimes because so many other people have)*.  Note that in your example that shorter cases can be more readable and fit on single lines without scroll bars.  Always try to ask the most minimal question.  If a 2 element array serves to demonstrate the point, why have a 4 element?  If an `int` can serve instead of a `bool` just as well to make a point, then integers `1` and `2` are briefer than `true`, `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
void analyze(Image * x, std::array<bool, 4> smooth = std::array<bool, 4>({true, true, true, false}));
```

And this works:

```
void analyze(Image * x, std::array<bool, 4> smooth = std::array<bool, 4>{true, true, true, false});
```

Which initializes the array with an initializer list. Your code had extra brackets.

Comment: Must be something with clang then... trying the second version gives expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Comment: @Luca : What _version_ of clang?

Comment: Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's your compiler that's the problem.
Here's a solution from pre C++11:

```
void analyze(Image* x, std::bitset<4> smooth = std::bitset("1110"));
```

You can also initialize `std::bitset` with a `unsigned long long`: `std::bitset(14ull)`